# How to show $\forall k < 0 , \exists h\in C^\infty(H) ~~\text{st}~~ \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 1}e^{-h}\partial_{xx}h=k$?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Denote $(x,t)\in H=R\times[0,1]$.

How to show $\forall k < 0 , \exists h(x,t)\in C^\infty(H) ~~\text{st}~~ \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 1}e^{-h}\partial_{xx}h=k$ ?

Comment: Try solving the ODE $e^{-h}h'' = k$. If you differentiate both sides and play around a bit you get $h'' - \frac{1}{2}(h')^2 = C$ for a different constant $C$. This should be easier to solve, and then construct $h(x,t)$ from the family of solutions you get.

Comment: @Jeff  Could you talk about it detail ? I don't understand it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the ODE
$$
e^{-h} h'' =k.
$$
Rearranging and multiplying by $h'$ shows that 
$$
\left(\frac{(h')^2}{2} \right)' =  h'' h' = k e^h h' = (k e^h)'
$$
and so we can integrate to get 
$$
(h')^2 = 2k e^h +a.
$$
Note that since $k < 0$ we have to pick $a >0$ in order for this to make sense. This is equivalent to 
$$
h' = \sqrt{a+2ke^h}.
$$
This is a separable ODE of the form
$$
\frac{dh}{\sqrt{a+2ke^h}} = dx,
$$
which can also be solved by integration.  We get
$$
-\frac{2}{\sqrt{a}} \text{arctanh}\left( \frac{\sqrt{a+2ke^h}}{\sqrt{a}}\right) = x + b,
$$
and we can then invert this to solve for $h$.  We could also flip the sign when we take the square root for the $h'$ equation to get a solution with the negative dropped at the arctanh.